# How to do automated UI testing of devexpress controls?

Tags: automated-tests, devexpress, ui-testing, gui-testing, testcafe

I want to do automated testing of DevExpress control.

I have found some frameworks like guia, NUnitForm etc. but they all are for standard WPF controls.

Is there any other framework which can help me to test DevExpress control?

Comment: I think this question is valid. DevExpress components tend to generate complex HTML and javascript and most UI-testing tools are not appropriate for them (as mentioned in the question). Evaluating whether a tool works with DevExpress requires considerable knowledge of the DevExpress components. The best place to share that knowledge is StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree with you @shamp00

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the DevExpress XAF framework, then DevExpress provide [EasyTests](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument3206). There is [some evidence](http://www.expandframework.com/blog/9-dennis-garavsky/283-functional-testing-of-non-xaf-apps-forms-based-on-certain-ms-and-devexpress-controls.html) that you could get EasyTests working with non-XAF applications - I'd ask in the [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Another option: DevExpress have recently launched [TestCafe](http://testcafe.devexpress.com/) which is definitely worth a look, but I don't have any experience with it yet. It is commercial software, but there is [a free evaluation available](http://testcafe.devexpress.com/Buy). It is not XAF-specific (nor even DevExpress-specific) and can target any web application.

You can also use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). It's not very easy because the DevExpress controls are complex and it's sometimes hard to find the right element to click on. Also, since a lot of AJAX calls take place you end up with a lot of `waitForElementPresent()` and so forth. For instance, your code might end up looking like this

```
selenium.type("xpath=//input[contains(@id,'_xaf_dviUserName_Edit_I')]", username);
selenium.type("xpath=//input[contains(@id,'_xaf_dviPassword_Edit_I')]", "");
selenium.click("Logon_PopupActions_Menu_DXI0_T");
```

That example is taken from my [blog post](http://blog.zerosharp.com/load-testing-xaf-part-2-selenium/) about automating testing against DevExpress expressAppFramework. I use the Firefox Selenium-IDE plugin to help find working syntax and then write scripts accordingly.

Finally, [a commercial product called Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/) claims to support DevExpress controls. I do not have any experience of it.

Comment: Update: now TestCafe goes to the open source - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Microsoft Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx). Disadvantage is that you need [Universal-Licence](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/) of DevExpress and at least Visual Studio (2012) Premium. Works fine in your projects.